# Why can't I get the array length of every string in the array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to get the length of an array's value(index?)
For some reason it is returning 1,0,0 and I am clueless why. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong please?
FYI this is from RubyMonk. I am trying to solve it without getting the answer..just need a little boost to figure out what im doing wrong

```
def length_finder(input_array)
 output= []
   input_array.length.times do |x|
    output << input_array.length[x]
   end
 return output
end
```

Comment: You might also want to try `Array.each`, which is a cleaner way to loop through the items (although kudos on the clever use of `times`)

Comment: You need the length of the array or the length of every element in the array?

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't it be:

```
output << input_array[x].length
```

Here you're using the [Bit reference method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Some more Ruby style:

```
def length_finder(input_array)
  input_array.map(&:length)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

That's very much over complicated and not idiomatic at all. Try this:

```
def length_finder(input_array)
  input_array.map { |x| x.size }
end
```

That should give you a new array, with the size of each child array as a member.

Comment: nice answer, +1 for the added value

Comment: Nice.. but OP didn't want an answer answer, just a fix to his question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def length_finder(input_array)
  output = []
  input_array.each do |x|
    output << x.length
  end
  return output
end

my_array = length_finder(["first", "second", "third", "forth"])
```